# What is the difference between auto&& y = x and auto& &y= x in modern C++?

Tags: c++

I would like to know the difference between the second and third lines is the following code:

```
int x = 10;
auto &&y = 10 ; // work without errors.
auto& &ry = 10; // compiler error "reference to reference is not allowed"
```

Comment: `&&` is not the same token as `& &`

Comment: The error message is quite clear: With the space, you have two separate `&` tokens, both meaning (lvalue) reference. And you can't have a reference to a reference.

Comment: If it wasn't an operator, but instead symbols, would you consider `foobar` to be the same as `foo bar`?

Comment: One has a space in the middle of an operator. You can't put a space in the middle of an operator. Well, mostly, for example you can put `int x = y ++ + + 2;`

Comment: I think an answer with an explanation which goes beyond "there is a blank" would be valuable here. What is `auto&&` (though it is not in the shown code)?  What is in contrast to that `auto&`? What is `&&y`? I.e. how is it not a reference to reference? Why does it not get an error?  If `&&` is an operator, what are the operands? For those operands, what do the two operators `& &` mean?

Comment: `& &` is different from `&&`, as `i n t` is different from `int`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of the [maximal munch principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).

In the first case of `auto &&y`, the `&&` is a single valid token(longest) and C++ grammar allows its use with `auto`, and so this succeeds.

While in the second case `auto& &`, the two `&` are also valid tokens(longest) **individually** and as the parser works from left to right, it is as if we're trying to have a reference to a reference which is not allowed and hence the error.

Basically in the first case `&&` is a single longest token while in second case `&` and `&` are two separate/individual tokens.

---

##### Example 2

You can also confirm that this is the case by replacing the latter `&` with `*` as shown below. Here we will get error because we can't have a pointer to a reference.

```
int & *i = 4; //ERROR because we can't have a pointer to a reference
```

The above will produced the expected error saying:

```
error: cannot declare pointer to ‘int&’
```

##### Example 3

We can do the same with two `*` individual token but this time we won't get any error because we can have a pointer to a pointer:

```
int i = 5;
int *j = &i;
int * *k = &j;   //VALID because even when there are 2 individual * tokens we can have a pointer to a pointer
```